# Is it possible that the same code runs differently in the same browser?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to brush up on my web coding skills (did that a looong time ago, and until now I was doing mainly WordPress styling), and since I have had 10+ of no coding at all, you can imagine..

Anyway, I've been doing this web development course from absolute scratch, and until now everything was going quite ok. That is, until JS while loops. I was given a task to create an instance of "how many fingers?" , in which the computer guesses the number the user inputs.

I did everything verbatim from the video, the usual way I do stuff the first time I'm learning. And the loop wouldn't stop, leading to a page crash.

Now, when I copied the code to my text editor from the source, it ran allright. Like I said, I did everything EXACTLY the same, I even indented the code in the same spots. I compared it several times, even asked my gf to tell me if there's something she sees that seems off (like a missing semi-colon or sth). Nothing.

Is this even possible? I'm quite frustrated, because I don't understand where the error came from, and I have tried looking online for a similar case and nothing... I do seem to have bad luck when it comes to computers, but...

I'd really appreciate the help - sorry for the quality of the code, like I said, I'm just starting (over) :) Here's the code that worked (and didn't work, they're exactly the same):

```js
document.getElementById("guess").onclick = function() {
 
 var myNumber = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
 
 var gotIt = false;
 
 var numberOfGuesses = 1;
 
 while (gotIt == false) {
 
  var guess = Math.random();

  guess = guess * 6;

  guess = Math.floor(guess);

  if (guess == myNumber) {
   
   gotIt = true;

   alert ("Got it! It was a " + guess + ". It took me " + numberOfGuesses + " guesses.");

  } else {

   numberOfGuesses++;

  }
 
 }
 
}
```

Comment: *"Is it possible that the same code runs differently in the same browser?"* - Probably not, and you're asking the entirely wrong question.  If and when the code fails, focus on what's making it fail.  Debug, observe, diagnose.  Whatever you're doing in your text editor is not debugging, asking your girlfriend is not debugging, debugging is debugging.  You claim that you've observed the loop to be running indefinitely, so that's a start.  The logic depends on randomness, so how often does this happen?  Can you add console output to your code so you can watch the values when it happens?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've failed to entirely show the steps that I've taken: there was absolutely no error in the code, no red exclamation marks, etc. and I've failed to open the console (I'm using Visual Studio Code with the option to "go live" as output) because the page would just crash.
Like I've said, I don't know what I'm doing yet, this is why my question might be wrong to you -> I still have to learn to ask the right questions :)

Comment: *"absolutely no error in the code"* - That's often an unfounded assumption when the code isn't working the way you expect it to.  A lack of a *syntax* error or *compilation* error does not mean the code is perfect.  If you're using Visual Studio, can you place debugging breakpoints in your loop?  Observe the ongoing iterations of the loop and the values of the variables.  If you can reliably replicate the problem, do so in the code snippet in the question above so we can also observe it.

Comment: I will do my best :) Thanks again!